# How to remove all newline characters from a text file generated from a java program running on a unix server?

Tags: java, unix

I have a java program which i am running on a Unix/Linux server. It generates a .txt file as the output which contain some long text strings which are being fetched from a DB table. 
I need one statement to appear in a single line so that no record statement gets continued in the next line in the output file.
I tried the following change in my code but it didn't help:

```
String s = "This is a String\nand all newline cha||rs\nshould be replaced in this example.";
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", " "));
```

although the above method works when i run the program on my widnows machine, it doesn't work on the server!!

Comment: what is the separator character in the original txt file?

Comment: Can you try this  s = s.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", " "); sop(s)

Comment: Your claim that the given code works on your personal machine but not on the server is dubious.  The actual case is almost surely that the code running on the server is different from that running on your personal machine, and that the latter is also not representative of the former.  Java does a reasonably good job of hiding differences between operating systems, but more importantly, the code you present in the question has no OS dependencies in the first place.

Comment: the separator character used is ",".

Comment: @JohnBollinger what I meant is that it works as expected on the windows machine but when ran on the server , if any statement in the output file is long enough, it automatically gets continues on the next line in the txt file. which is what I need to counter.

Comment: In that case, @Ron9794, edit the question to say what you really mean, and replace the irrelevant code in it with code that actually demonstrates the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Hi! i think i got the root cause of my problem here! when i opened the output txt file generated in my unix box in vi mode, it had some records which contained (control-M) characters in between. i think that is the reason why some records are having new line characters when opened in windows(notepad, notepad++). My question is, how do i add the logic to remove those characters in my java code?